# Show/hide button in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am new with Sencha Touch and I have the following method:

```
    toggleProfitability: function (button) {
        var tspStatus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#tspstatus');
        var vbsStatus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#vbsstatus');
        if (tspStatus.length && vbsStatus.length > 0) {
            Ext.each(tspStatus, function (item) {
                Ext.fly(item.id).hide();
            });
            Ext.each(vbsStatus, function (item) {
                Ext.fly(item.id).hide();
            });
        }
        // close Menu
        button.up('cartMenuPanel').hide();
    },
```

At the bottom of the code above I am making a call to the `hide` method but I am unsure how to show the hidden fields again afterwards, Could anyone suggest a way to do this?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and now it´s working...

```
    toggleProfitability: function (button) {
    var listItems = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('cartItems cartItem');
    Ext.each(listItems, function (item) {
        var tsp = item.down('[name=tspstatus]');
        var vbs = item.down('[name=vbsstatus]');
        tsp.setHidden(!vbs.getHidden());
        vbs.setHidden(!vbs.getHidden());

    }, this);
    // close Menu
    button.up('cartMenuPanel').hide();
},
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check the visibility state of the items and toggle their visibility in your button handler where it is defined:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    handler: function() {
        var tspStatus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#tspstatus')[0];
        var vbsStatus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#vbsstatus')[0];

        if (tspStatus.isVisible() && vbsStatus.isVisible()) {
             tspStatus.hide();
             vbsStatus.hide();
        } else {
             tspStatus.show();
             vbsStatus.show();
        }
    },
    text: 'Show/Hide'
}
```

As spotted by Rob below in the commnets, if you would expect the results of the ComponentQuery to return multiple components you would need to iterate over the results using something like [Ext.each](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext-method-each) and remove the `[0]` at the end of those lines.

Comment: Sorry, but it is not working for me, You can see my explanation in the next comment..

Comment: yes, as @rob has said your hiding items that we cannot see code for. what exactly are you trying to acheive. It would be much easier to help with this if you code show all the code that is specific to this issue and explain what you require. Or even better create a [Fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) replicating the issue

Comment: Simply, I would like hiding "vbsStatus" and "tspStatus" from a button and show in next time...hide/show everytime.  Thanks for your help

Comment: I have updated the code to show how you might toggle the visibility of those particular items in the handler of the button

Comment: @Scriptable your code is not quite correct but I think you're definitely on track.  The OP's question isn't particularly clear! `Ext.ComponentQuery.query`returns an array so you'll have to refer to the first element e.g. `var tspStatus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#tspstatus')[0];`

Comment: At the moment I have the following error: Cannot read property 'isVisible' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot do anything is since you are actually hiding the parent container of the button for starters.

If you can put your button in a different place then you'll be able to apply logic on each click of the button.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            fullscreen: true,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Test Panel',
                html: 'Some html here',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    docked: 'top',
                    title: 'My Toolbar'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                handler: this.toggleProfitability,
                text: 'Toggle Panel'
            }]
        })

    },

    toggleProfitability: function(button) {
        /*var tspStatus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#tspstatus');
        var vbsStatus = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#vbsstatus');
        if (tspStatus.length && vbsStatus.length > 0) {
            Ext.each(tspStatus, function(item) {
                Ext.fly(item.id).hide();
            });
            Ext.each(vbsStatus, function(item) {
                Ext.fly(item.id).hide();
            });
        }
        // close Menu
        button.up('cartMenuPanel').hide();*/

        // First get the target
        var myTarget = button.up('panel').child('panel');

        // Now set hidden as the opposite value of `hidden`
        myTarget.setHidden(!myTarget.getHidden());
    }
});
```

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gbh

Comment: It is not working for me, in  my code I should hide "vbStatus" and "tspStatus" when I send an event, firing toggleProfitability method

Comment: @inane you're question code certainly don't demonstrate what you just commented but in that case have a look at my comment above in relation to @Scriptable's answer.  My code is an example of how you would  `toggle` the visibility of an element/component.